# Using Ngrx DevTools with Ionic 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ngrx-store, ionic5, redux-devtools

I am trying to follow [this link](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ngrx-devtools/) to use the Ngrx DevTools. But Ionic uses @ionic/angular-toolkit, and we need to enable the Ngrx Schematics which replaces that. Is there a way to have both?

```
Changes in Angular.json
  "cli": {
--"defaultCollection": "@ionic/angular-toolkit"
++"defaultCollection": "@ngrx/schematics"
},
```

> @ionic/angular-toolkit: Angular Schematics and Builders for @ionic/angular apps

Comment: [Link to @ionic/angular-toolkit](https://github.com/ionic-team/angular-toolkit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to use the ngrx schematics to generate my stores for my Ionic 5 app by:

1. installing the @ngrx/schematics and allowing them to replace the @ionic/angular-toolkit.
2. running "ng generate store..."
3. replacing the "defaultCollection" entry with "@ionic/angular-toolkit"

This seemed to allow me to get it done -- until Ionic provides an update to their schematics for this.

Yes, this is a hack, and requires me to do this each time that I want to gen a store,  but it allows me to use ngrx tools, would like to learn a cleaner way from someone!

Comment: Nice, so add the store and roll the schematics back again. Seams to be the only way until Ionic team updates their schematics. Thanks!

Comment: Helped me as well. Too bad the ngrx schematics don't work when you add this

Answer (score 1):

1. Install @ngrx/store-devtools
2. Add "StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({ maxAge: 30 })" in imports in app.module.ts